# Can't use foreach value in mysql where

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I'm using a foreach loop to get data, and then using the data to get information from the database.
But when using `$main[0]->group_number` (text not integer) then it returns wrong data, like 015 == 01

```
Product::Budget($budget_id)->Active(1)->Parent($main[0]->group_number)->get();
```

But when i put $main[0]->group_number in a $string then it returns correct data.

```
$value = $main[0]->group_number;
Product::Budget($budget_id)->Active(1)->Parent($value)->get();
```

Now it returns correct data, 01==01 and 015==015

Why does the first one return wrong data and the second one correct data?

```
// This takes data from another table and puts it into $main
@foreach($groups->insideGroup($budget_id, $group->number, null, 2) as $main)
    // This takes data from the last table and puts it into $job, but if using $main value in the Parent() scope, it returns wrong values. Except when putting the value into $string
    @foreach(Job::Budget($budget_id)->Active(1)->Parent($main[0]->group_number)->get() as $job)
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: @ling.s updated my first post

Comment: Don't use nested foreach loops. I believe that PHP is using some internal pointers so the two foreach loops affect each other's position. Instead use a normal for loop.

Comment: But can you explain why can't I use the first foreach $main[0]->group number in the second foreach, instead it returns wrong data. But if I put the first foreach $main in a $string then the second foreach returns correct data?

Comment: Because the key is `$main` only

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is PHP's type juggling at work.
you can test this out using:

```
var_dump(015);
var_dump('015');
```

PHP treats the first one as an octal number
`http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php`

Comment: Both $string = $main[0]->group_number and $main[0]->group_number return as 'string' but only $string works in the query so that it returns correct data.